# "list items" or "list's item": A compound noun or possessive?

Tags: grammar, possessives, compound-nouns

If we are referring the items belong to a list, it sounds like a list in this case is a possessive noun: "the items of a list".

However, the google says that a form "the list items" is also frequently used. "the list items" sounds like a compound noun but with some taste of possession.

Is there any rule that dictates whether we should use possessive forms or noun+noun in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule of grammar mandating one form or the other in such a case.  One could think of the items as belonging to or associated with a list, and say or write

> The list's items

to refer to them. But each item is correctly called a "list item" and so several of them could be called:

> the list items.

Or one could use an of-form, as :

> The items of the list.

Or one could say:

> The items on the list.

The choice is largely one of style.  [This Googler Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+list%27s+items%2Cthe+list+items%2CThe+items+of+the+list%2CThe+items+on+the+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20list%20items%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThe%20items%20of%20the%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThe%20items%20on%20the%20list%3B%2Cc0) shows  "the list items" to be significantly more frequent. This is subject to all the usual caution about the use of Google Ngrams.

I personally would prefer "*the list items*" in most circumstances. The possessive form could easily be mistaken for a miss-use of an apostrophe in pluralizing (the so-called "greengrocer's apostrophe"). Besides it just seems a bit awkward to me. The forms with "of" are longer to no real purpose, and seem a bit stiff to me, but  I would prefer them to the possessive form.

Answer (score 1):

No rule, just convention. "*The list items*" happens to be a natural way to express the idea of "*the items of the list*", and because it's shorter and has no repetition, it's preferred.

In contrast, "*the shelf items*" isn't a natural way to express the idea of "*the items on the shelf*".